# Python, selenium - why do i get this error?

Tags: python, selenium, google-maps

I want to access google maps with python, but at first you have to click accept cookies button and I don't know why but I keep getting this error:

> File "file", line 12, in 
> WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
> '//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]'))).click()   File
> "C:\Users\gassp\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py",
> line 80, in until
> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('PATH')
url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/'

driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchboxinput"]'))).send_keys('gostilne')
driver.submit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it didn't change between the main frame and the accept cookie frame. Here is the soulution code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\gassp\\OneDrive\\Namizje\\Python.projects\\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/'

driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="consent-bump"]/div/div[1]/iframe')))
agree = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]/span/span'))) 
agree.click()

#back to the main page
driver.switch_to_default_content()


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchboxinput"]'))).send_keys('gostilne')
driver.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html :

> exception selenium.common.exceptions.**TimeoutException**(msg=None, screen=None, stacktrace=None)
> Bases: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException
> Thrown when a command does not complete in enough time.

Hence you either need to increase the time in `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` or check if the condition `EC.element_to_be_clickable` is even fulfillable.

---

Furthermore, try the following implementation:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]')))
element.click()
```

That fixed a few problems at my end with a similar code structure.

Comment: I tried to increase the time to 10 and it still gives me the same error. Any other ideas? Or can  the error be that this accept cookie window is a pop up window?

Comment: @gasper_vaupot Is the element you are referring to hidden? ... is it clickable? With the information you're providing us it's hard to find any kind of solution for your problem. As mentioned, according to the official Selenium documentation, `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` (the error you're receiving) is referring to the following issue: `a command does not complete in enough time`.

Comment: I don't understand how the time system works. If i increase the number the wait time also increases right? Meaning if i change the number with 30 instead of 10 it shoud wait a little longer correct?

Comment: @gasper_vaupot Take a look at explicit waits (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html): The statement  `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]')))`waits 10 seconds at **a maximum** for the element you've given via XPath. If the element isn't found, a `TimeoutException` (the one you're getting) is given! So the element is either not clickable or not there (maybe the wrong XPath?).

Comment: Is there a way so that i can send a picture of what i want to click? So that you vould know exactly what i mean

Comment: @gasper_vaupot You could include the HTML code of the page you're trying to access, but as I've just seen another user has discovered that the element was in fact wrongly declared by you - that should fix your problem!

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to access the site I did not found the xpath locator `//*[@id="introAgreeButton"]` in chrome dev tool. Not sure what element it refers to.

However when I commented that line and added the click event on the search button, I was able to get the results.

Also there is no `submit()` method available on driver instance.

Below was my trial using the code you have provided -

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchboxinput"]'))).send_keys('gostilne')
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@id='searchbox-searchbutton']"))).click()
```

**Output :-**

[image]

Comment: The problem I am having is before that. When i run my code it opens a new Google Maps tab but before i can do anything since i am not logged it i have to click accept cookies button and that's where my problem is

Comment: I just posted the picture of what i want to click down here

Comment: Post it in your question itself this part of this thread is for answers only

Comment: @gasper_vaupot  I'm not getting that popup at my end